# Why my app crashes when I run a Runnable thread in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to run a thread when a specifically method is called. Like this:

```
private void changeSize(final Bitmap image) {
  Thread task = new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
            byte[] image;
            int width = image.getWidth();
            int height = image.getHeight();
            int newHeight = 0, newWidth = 0;
            if (width > 350 || height > 350) {
                if (width > height) { 
                    newHeight = 350;
                    newWidth = (newHeight * width) / height;
                } else { 
                    nyBredden = 350;
                    newHeight = (newWidth * height) / width;
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            Bitmap sizeChanged = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight, true);
            if (sizeChanged != null) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            if (sizeChanged.getHeight() >= 350 || sizeChanged.getWidth() >= 350) {
                sizeChanged.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
            } else {
                sizeChanged.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            }

            image = stream.toByteArray();
            if (image != null) {
                myImage(image); //method
                File path = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                String namechanged = edMyType.getText().toString() + "_scalledDown" + ".jpg";

                File file = new File(path, namechanged);
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    fos.write(image);
                    fos.flush();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (fos != null) {
                            fos.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
     }
  });
  task.start(); 
}
```

when i call this method my app crashes. I tried to debug, but i don't understand the variables for example:

```
task: "Thread[Thread-149,5,main]"
hasBeenStarted = false
```

The method is called when i press a button to take a picture. Please any one knows where i did wrong or is it correct to run a thread like this?

Comment: post the logcat output!

Comment: what is some code ??

Comment: post the logic inside the runnable.

Comment: Everything seems correct, Problem is somewhere else please post you locat trace.

Comment: @Preethi Rao: I'm showing the entire code now.

Comment: Toast you cannot show in background thread.. Which totally wrong. Shift to main thread and display

Comment: @Preethi Rao: tried without toasts and i'm getting the same crash!

Comment: @Preethi Ra: i'm getting this: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from this loop only ?

Comment: @Preethi Ra: myImage(image); i have this method inside the thread which is showing a toast. I delete the toast and it went well, but i wanna get the value from this method. How to do that?

Comment: The problem was with the toast. You cant use any ui Related thing in some other thread. So if you want any ui related things just use runOnUiThread() inside your thread. Everything else will be fine

Comment: Do you mean instead of: `Thread` like this: 

`MyActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {`

            `@Override`
           ` public void run() {`
                `Toast.makeText(MyActivityName.this, "This is Toast!!!",``Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

            `}`
        `});` or inside the `Thread`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78540/discussion-between-preethi-rao-and-carl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot display `Toast`s in a background thread.

Either remove the toasts and use e.g. logging for debugging purposes, or transfer the toasts to the main UI thread by using e.g. `Activity` `runOnUiThread()` or a `Handler`.

Comment: But the context is the Activity which have the code.

Comment: The context doesn't matter. Toasts only work on the UI thread.

Comment: I tried without toasts and i'm getting the same crash!

Comment: ... which is? Post your syacktrace to learn about other problems in the code.

Comment: myImage(image); i have this method inside the thread which is showing a toast. I delete the toast and it went well, but i wanna get the value from this method. How to do that? - It was a test, for trying to see if i can send something from the thread!

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`: this showed me the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps!

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run()

                {   
                         //do your stuff here ,but you canot update ui from any other thread
 }
            }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use Handler...

```
private void changeSize(final Bitmap image) {
 Thread task = new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {

     }
      private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
           //some code here..
      };
 });
 task.start(); 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        splashThread.start();
```

try with  my code. I hope this will help you.